# Automapper: How to specify a type conversion once for multiple properties

Tags: automapper

I'm using Automapper to map from an object that contains a lot of home-grown "StringType" and "DateTimeType" fields that I want to automap into the standard System.string, System.DateTime.  Is there a way to do this without having to register every single member on the source object?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<StringType, string>()
            .ForAllMembers(q =>
                {
                    q.NullSubstitute(string.Empty);
                    q.MapFrom(p => p.Value);
                });
        Mapper.CreateMap<DateTimeType, DateTime>()
            .ForAllMembers(q =>
            {
                q.NullSubstitute(DateTime.MinValue);
                q.MapFrom(p => p.Value);
            });
        Mapper.CreateMap<InType, OutType>();
```

I keep getting "source object is null" exceptions when I try to do an actual conversion from "InType" to "OutType."  I've tried defining the conversion via ValueResolvers, but that didn't help.

What is the right way to do this?  (I've seen similar questions on stackoverflow, but the answers I've seen all suggest involved configuration steps and/or downloading yet another library to handle this situation:  in all such cases my own solution would be to dump Automapper and go with a hand-written conversion, saving time and making the code more readable all at once.)

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at custom type converters ?

I think that should do the trick...

This link is not that "young", but I looked at it few weeks ago, and it was still usefull

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/06/automapper-feature-custom-type-converters/

You would have something like that (untested)

```
public class StringTypeToStringResolver : ITypeConverter<StringType, string> {
    public string Convert(StringType source) {
        return source == null ? string.Empty : source.Value;
    }
}
```

and a Mapping declaration like that

```
Mapper.CreateMap<StringType, string>().ConvertUsing(new StringTypeToStringResolver());
Mapper.CreateMap<InType, OutType>();
```